# calculate proportion in grouped data frame

Tags: r

I have the following data frame :

```
  year  owngun    N
1 2000     Yes  603
2 2000      No 1231
3 2000 Refused   23
4 2012     Yes  440
5 2012      No  841
6 2012 Refused   24
```

How can I make a column to have the proportions for each `year` and level of `owngun`?

Comment: There is only a single observation for each group.  SO the proportion is 1.

Comment: @Robert You're right,but is there a way to add a new column in the data frame to have also the proportions?

Comment: Your question was not clear bcs you said for each year and level of owngun.  Anyway, I posted a solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming your N's are already your aggregated counts, you could get proportions using `data.table`:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[,prop:=N/sum(N),by=year]
df

   year  owngun    N       prop
1: 2000     Yes  603 0.32471729
2: 2000      No 1231 0.66289715
3: 2000 Refused   23 0.01238557
4: 2012     Yes  440 0.33716475
5: 2012      No  841 0.64444444
6: 2012 Refused   24 0.01839080
```

Same approach using `plyr`:

```
library(plyr)     
df2<-ddply(df,.(year),transform,prop=N/sum(N))
```

Comment: Thank you very much that's what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 1):

We can use `ave` from `base R`

```
df1$prop <- with(df1, N/ave(N, year, FUN = sum))
df1$prop
#[1] 0.32471729 0.66289715 0.01238557 0.33716475 0.64444444 0.01839080
```

---

Or another option with `tapply`

```
with(df1, prop.table(tapply(N, list(year, owngun), FUN = sum), 1))
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 >df

   year  owngun    N
 1 2000     Yes  603
 2 2000      No 1231
 3 2000 Refused   23
 4 2012     Yes  440
 5 2012      No  841
 6 2012 Refused   24

 >library(dplyr)

 > df %>% group_by(year)  %>% mutate(Proportion=N/sum(N))


      year  owngun    N  Proportion
     (int)  (fctr) (int)     (dbl)
  1  2000     Yes   603  0.32471729
  2  2000      No  1231  0.66289715
  3  2000 Refused    23  0.01238557
  4  2012     Yes   440  0.33716475
  5  2012      No   841  0.64444444
  6  2012 Refused    24  0.01839080
```

Answer (score 0):

Is that what you want?

```
ndf<-reshape2::dcast(dfr[,-1], owngun ~ year)
ndf$p2000=ndf$`2000`/rowSums(ndf[,-1])
ndf$p2012=ndf$`2012`/rowSums(ndf[,-1])
ndf[c(3,1,2),]
```

Proportion of year by level of owngun

```
   owngun 2000 2012     p2000     p2012
3     Yes  603  440 0.5781400 0.4216263
1      No 1231  841 0.5941120 0.4057717
2 Refused   23   24 0.4893617 0.5053763
```

Proportion of owngun by year

```
ndf<-reshape2::dcast(dfr[,-1], year ~ owngun)
cbind(year=ndf$year,(100*ndf[,-1]/apply(ndf[,-1], 1, sum))[,c(3,1,2)])

  year      Yes       No  Refused
1 2000 32.47173 66.28971 1.238557
2 2012 33.71648 64.44444 1.839080
```

Comment: I'm looking for proportion for each level of owngun and year.For example the proportion of level Yes in year 2000 is calculated as : 630/(630+1231+23)

Answer (score 0):

`prop.table` and `xtabs` could be a handy tool:

```
library(magrittr)
xtabs(N ~., df) %>% prop.table(1) %>% round(2)

#      owngun
#year     No Refused  Yes
#  2000 0.66    0.01 0.32
#  2012 0.64    0.02 0.34
```